# How to prevent Jenkins parallel stages in pipeline to create a new workspace?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline that executes this way:

```
Stage 1  -----> Stage 2  ----> Stage4
clone repo  |   exec           email   
            |                  results
            --> Stage 3
                exec
```

Stage 1, 2 and 3 all execute inside a docker image, all of them sharing a network directory for the workspaces.

My problem is that when Stage 3 starts, it fails because the cloned files aren't there. Stage 3 created a new workspace named `MyJobName@2` and it is empty. It looks like the problem just happens when there are parallel stages.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, below is my original answer that still fails. My installation used an older docker version and I always get the error:

```
Docker version is older than 17.12, working directory will be /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ICP-bdm-Revisao not /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ICP-bdm-Revisao@2
```

I thought the problem was solved, but when I started to use more parallel stages the problem came back.

I tried these 3 solutions and they **failed**:

- dir (myWorkspace) {...}
- ws (myWorkspace) {...}
- node {customWorkspace myWorkspace}

My even more hacky solution was to change every command to use absolute paths or to `cd` to the directory before executing each shell command.

---

Old answer that should work if you have an older docker:

Here is my very hacky solution. I couldn't prevent Jenkins to create a different pipeline to each stage, so my solution was:

1. In first stage put the current workspace in a global variable called `myWorkspace`
2. For each other stage, enclose the commands in the step inside a command `dir (myWorkspace) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple steps into one stage. Then the steps share on Workspace.

If stage3 is only there to email results, you should use archive artifacts and then emails the results.

Comment: Can multiple steps in one stage have a parallel execution?

Comment: You can out the steps from stage 4 in both stage 3 and stage 2

Answer (score 0):

You can set the workspace for every stage seperately so in your example Stage 2 and 4 would share the same workspace. For stage 3 you would have to set a different `customWorkspace`
Code would be like the following:

```
        stage('Pipeline Test')
        {
                stage('Test')
                {
                    agent
                    {
                        node
                        {
                            customWorkspace 'workspace/justATest'
                        }
                    }
                    steps
                    {
                      //everything is executed in the workspace declared above
                    }
```

Comment: I'm using declarative pipelines, so I don't have the `node` option. How would I configure it?

Comment: Are you sure you use a declarative pipeline? My code example can be used for it (Jenkinsfile) so it should work fine.

Comment: Does not work, it didn't obey my configured path.  I tried to set :  `parallel {
                stage('Hom') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            image "${imageBuild}"
                            args "${dockerArgs}"
                            customWorkspace "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyJobName" 
                        }
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. I have a Jenkinsfile where [each stage runs in its own containter](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-multiple-containers) and some stages run in parallel.

The main difference is that I use a Declarative pipeline for which the workspace is more or less defined after the git clone. This means that both workspace `MyJobName` (of stage 2) and `MyJobName@2` (of stage 3) contain the repo with the latest commits.

This basicly already solves the problem you stated, but I needed more.

In stage 4, I needed the results of stage 2 AND stage 3. But in stage 4 only the workspace `MyJobName` is available, not workspace `MyJobName@2`.

For this I used the [caching data for containers](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#caching-data-for-containers) trick.

Comment: I don't understand.  How does setting up a Docker command like these result in retaining the files in the workspace?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski the Docker argument creates a volume. This volume is gives you a persistent directory outside to lifecycle of a container (which only lives for a single stage). Does this makes it clear?